# Flex advance datagrid and dash(-)

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

For one of my grid column , xml data is like

[image]

But on the grid , dash (-) gets converted into `&#8211` character , like

[image]

What's best solution without any change in original data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is to add a renderer to the column definition you want to modify then in the custom renderer just use a label or a text object if you need wrapping, I haven't seen that behavior before though, pretty strange.

Comment: Hey Shaun,It seems it's not a dash character. It's more like Unicode em dash character. So, I assume best bet is to fix the data.

Comment: Hey Rishi sorry I didn't post back earlier, yah that sounds like a better solution, did you end up going with that (if so I'm assuming the problem was basically a Unicode->ASCII conversion that couldn't take place or something along those lines?